# User login error by JWT (Postman POST token)

Tags: json, asp.net-core, jwt

I have created a user login system that uses the JWT token. I followed the instructions in a course.

By entering correct login details in Postman, the token is generated correctly.
Then I send a Get query to a random method (adds Authorization header "Bearer [token]"). The method is called, but without the user.

While the method is running, I check Claims in QuickWatch "HttpContext.User" and they are missing (there should be a username, age, etc.)

Can someone help me? Thank you

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "jwt": {
    "JwtKey": "JWT_KEYsomethingyouwantwhichissecurewillworkk",
    "JwtIssuer": "https://meetupapi.com",
    "JwtExpireDays": 15
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**JwtProvider Class**

```
public class JwtProvider : IJwtProvider 
    {
        private readonly JwtOptions _jwtOptions;
        public JwtProvider(JwtOptions jwtOptions)
        {
            this._jwtOptions = jwtOptions;
        }

        public string GenerateJwtToken(User user)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>()
            { 
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.RoleName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email),
                new Claim("DateOfBirth", user.DateOfBirth.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")),
                new Claim("Nationality", user.Nationality)
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_jwtOptions.JwtKey));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(_jwtOptions.JwtExpireDays);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_jwtOptions.JwtIssuer, _jwtOptions.JwtIssuer, claims, expires: expires, signingCredentials: creds);

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my whole working demo:

Model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
public class Role
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
public class JwtOptions
{
    public string JwtKey { get; set; } 
    public string JwtIssuer { get; set; } 
    public int JwtExpireDays { get; set; } 
}
```

IJwtProvider:

```
public interface IJwtProvider
{
    string GenerateJwtToken(User user);
}
```

JwtProvider:

```
public class JwtProvider : IJwtProvider
{
    private readonly JwtOptions _jwtOptions;
    public JwtProvider(JwtOptions jwtOptions)
    {
        this._jwtOptions = jwtOptions;
    }

    public string GenerateJwtToken(User user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.RoleName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email),
            new Claim("DateOfBirth", user.DateOfBirth.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")),
            new Claim("Nationality", user.Nationality)
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_jwtOptions.JwtKey));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(_jwtOptions.JwtExpireDays);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_jwtOptions.JwtIssuer, _jwtOptions.JwtIssuer, claims, expires: expires, signingCredentials: creds);

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson();

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:JwtIssuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:JwtIssuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:JwtKey"])),

                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    RequireSignedTokens = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0)
                };
            });

        //services.AddScoped<JwtOptions>();
        services.AddScoped<IJwtProvider>(serviceprovider=>
            new JwtProvider(new JwtOptions() { 
                JwtKey= Configuration["Jwt:JwtKey"],
                JwtIssuer= Configuration["Jwt:JwtIssuer"],
                JwtExpireDays=int.Parse(Configuration["Jwt:JwtExpireDays"])
            }));         
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication(); //be sure add this line...
        
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[Controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IJwtProvider _provider;
    public ValuesController(IJwtProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;            
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        var claims = HttpContext.User.Claims;
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody]User user)
    {
        var data = _provider.GenerateJwtToken(user);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]